# Querying a SQL Query for Distinct Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery

I have a SQL Query that joins 3 tables and pulls 3 total columns out of them. I was try to figure out how to Query that Query to get distinct records from only one of the columns. Here is what I have so far

```
Select Distinct Make.NAME
                From
            (
                Select MakeModel.MAKE_ID, Make.NAME, Vehicle.MODEL_YR
                From NagsInfo.dbo.Make
                INNER JOIN NagsInfo.dbo.MakeModel
                    on Make.MAKE_ID = MakeModel.MAKE_ID
                INNER JOIN NagsInfo.dbo.Vehicle
                    on MakeModel.MAKE_MODEL_ID = Vehicle.MAKE_MODEL_ID
                Where Vehicle.MODEL_YR = @YEAR
            )
```

I keep getting multiple different syntax errors, I believe the most recent one telling me that the parentheses were incorrect, but everywhere I looked they are required for Sub queries.

Comment: You have to alias the derived table, like `) AS Make`. Apart from that, you can just select one column and apply `DISTINCT` on  this column.

Comment: `Select DISTINCT Make.NAME
                From NagsInfo.dbo.Make
                INNER JOIN NagsInfo.dbo.MakeModel
                    on Make.MAKE_ID = MakeModel.MAKE_ID
                INNER JOIN NagsInfo.dbo.Vehicle
                    on MakeModel.MAKE_MODEL_ID = Vehicle.MAKE_MODEL_ID
                Where Vehicle.MODEL_YR = @YEAR`

Comment: Thank you so much. Nowhere I looked seemed to want to give me that tiny bit of information.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - `DISTINCT` is applied to the entire `SELECT` set, or row if you'd like, not to a specific column.

Comment: @Amit I agree with you. This is what I' m trying to say in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use a subquery at all? Why not just do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.NAME
FROM NagsInfo.dbo.Make M
JOIN NagsInfo.dbo.MakeModel MM ON M.MAKE_ID = MM.MAKE_ID
JOIN NagsInfo.dbo.Vehicle V ON MM.MAKE_MODEL_ID = V.MAKE_MODEL_ID
WHERE V.MODEL_YR = @YEAR
```

Comment: Well, for some reason I had it in my head that doing it like this wasn't possible, but seeing this has now made me realize the conclusion I came to earlier is very wrong. Thank you for help.